# How to change capitalization of a name in taxonomy using CSOM?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online, csom

Does anyone know how to use CSOM to update a taxonomy item (ex. term group, term set) name capitalization? For example, there is one term group named 'kelvin', how to change it to 'Kelvin'?

Here is my code,

```
var termGroup = termStore.GetGroup(id);
context.Load(termGroup);
context.ExecuteQuery();

termGroup.Name = "Kelvin";
termStore.CommitAll();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

There is no error or exception, but the name does not get updated.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the term group to something else different and change back to the correct name with correct casing. I found out that you don't need to do this for Term set

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, this is a good idea. But for labels, I guess the only way is to delete and create again.